# Get parameters of many 3D objects

Tags: c#

I'm working again on the 3D model of a building in order to parse in `JSON` every parameters of every objects of the model. My program works well but it is too slow because of the huge number of information : about ~10k objects each containing ~20 parameters. In order to get a lighter `JSON` we organize it this way :

```
{
    "Model": { //general information about the 3D model
    },
    "Types" : [ // types relatives parameters
    {
       "Object": { //general information about a specific type (family of objects)
       },
       "Parameters": [ //list of every ID and value of a specific parameter
       ]
    }],
    "Occurrences" : [ // object relatives parameters
    {
        "Object": { //general information about a specific object
        },
        "Parameters": [ //pair of every ID and value of a specific parameter
        ]
    }],
    "DefinitionsTypes": [ // More informations about a type relative parameter 
                          //(name, IsReadOnly...)
    ],
    "DefinitionsObjects": [ //More informations about an occurrences relative parameter
    ]
}
```

Using `StopWatch` I know which parts of the code is taking most of the execution time. It is obviously the loop getting parameters on occurrences. Before posting here I try to optimize the code by myself.

- I replace `List` I knew the length by `arrays`
- I remove useless `if` and `query`
- I replace as much `foreach` loops by `for` loops as I could

At the end it comes to a nice result :

- Execution time from 825 seconds to 333
- Json file of 129 mO

So the goal is to make it as faster and lighter as possible ! Here is the sample taking most of the time :

```
for (int i = 0; i < elems.Length; i++) //elems contains every occurrences
            {
                //method to get small amount of information about the
                //occurrence itself (name, ID)
                objectData = JsonObjectData.GetJsonObjectData(elems[i]); 
                //array which contains every parameter of the occurrence 
                // GetOrderedParameters is a method from the Revit API
                Parameter[] paramArray = elems[i].GetOrderedParameters().ToArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < paramArray.Length; j++)
                {
                    // GetJsonDef is a custom method (definition below)
                    objectDefIn.Add(Param.GetJsonDef(paramArray[j]));
                }
                // custom method as well
                parameterData = Param.GetJsonParameterData(elems[i], objectData);
                paramObjectList.Add(parameterData);
            }
```

`GetJsonDef` method :

```
public static ParamDef GetJsonDef(Parameter p)
        {
            //ParamDef is a public struct 
            ParamDef instance = new ParamDef();
            string format = "NoID?";

            if (p.IsShared) //we distinguish shared parameter and builtin
            {
                format = p.GUID.ToString();
                instance = new ParamDef { Name = p.Definition.Name,
                Id = format, UserModifiable = p.UserModifiable,
                IsReadOnly = p.IsReadOnly };
            }
            else
            {
                format = p.Id.ToString();
                instance = new ParamDef { Name = p.Definition.Name,
                Id = format, UserModifiable = p.UserModifiable, 
                IsReadOnly = p.IsReadOnly };
            }

            return instance;

        }
```

`GetJsonParameterData` Method :

```
public static Param GetJsonParameterData
(Element element, JsonObjectData objectData /*Info about the object itself*/)
        {
            // Param is the class (a JsonObjectData and two List of public struct, to distinguish shared parameters)

            Param param = new Param();
            List<ParamList> instance = new List<ParamList>();
            List<ParamList> instanceShared = new List<ParamList>();
            Parameter[] paramArray = element.GetOrderedParameters().ToArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < paramArray.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!paramArray[j].IsShared)
                {
                    string value = paramArray[j].AsValueString();
                    string format = paramArray[j].Id.ToString();
                    ParamList pair = new ParamList { Id = format, Value = value };
                    instance.Add(pair);
                }
                else
                {
                    string value = paramArray[j].AsValueString();
                    string format = paramArray[j].GUID.ToString();
                    ParamList pair = new ParamList { Id = format, Value = value };
                    instanceShared.Add(pair);
                }

            }
            param.Object = objectData;
            param.ObjectParameters = instance;
            param.SharedParameters = instanceShared;
            return param;
        }
```

Sorry for the long post, I hope it is not too heavy or/and hard to read,

Thank you for your attention anyway !

Comment: Initialize your `instance` and `instanceShared` lists with `paramArray.Length`. You'll waste a bit of memory by over provisioning them, but you'll save time by the lists not having to resize as you add elements. Other than that, use a profiler to get more detailed information about where you're spending the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `GetJsonDef()` method, they only difference between the `if..else`branches is the value of the `format` variable. This `format` variable can just be initialized to `null` because you are nevertheless assigning a value to it.

You are assigning a `new ParamDef()` to the `instance` variable and later on overwriting it.

This whole method can be simplified to

```
public static ParamDef GetJsonDef(Parameter p)
{
    string format = null;

    if (p.IsShared) //we distinguish shared parameter and builtin
    {
        format = p.GUID.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        format = p.Id.ToString();
    }

    return new ParamDef { Name = p.Definition.Name,
    Id = format, UserModifiable = p.UserModifiable,
    IsReadOnly = p.IsReadOnly };

}
```

You could use a ternary expression as well instead of the `if..else` like @eurotrash mentioned in the comment like so

```
string format = p.IsShared ? p.GUID.ToString() : p.Id.ToString();
```

in the same way you should change the `if..else` of the `GetJsonParameterData()` method.

Comment: Could you not reduce further to `string format = p.IsShared ? p.GUID.ToString() : p.Id.ToString();`?

Comment: @eurotrash good point, edited into the answer.

Comment: Thank you ! The Execution time is now 229 seconds which represent a great improvement ! 
@RobH I'm gonna try to provide a profiler.
Any other ideas are welcome !